# Spring JWT authentication with ".hasAuthority()" returning "insufficient scope" error

Tags: java, spring, jwt, authorization

I'm using JWT as authentication for Spring right now. I'm also using a custom `AppUser` entity with custom `Authority`.

Here's the code for these entities:

**AppUser entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="app_user")
public class AppUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    ...

    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="authority_id", columnDefinition = "INT NOT NULL")
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    ...
}
```

**Authority entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="authority")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="authority", columnDefinition =
            "ENUM('TRIAL', 'ESSENTIAL', 'PREMIUM', 'ADMIN') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TRIAL'")
    private AuthorityType authority = AuthorityType.TRIAL;

    @JsonBackReference
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="app_user_id", columnDefinition = "INT NOT NULL")
    private AppUser appUser;
    ...
}
```

Also here's my security config and custom UserDetailsServcie:

**SecurityConfig**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private JwtSecretProvider jwtSecretProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, JwtSecretProvider jwtSecretProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        this.jwtSecretProvider = jwtSecretProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> {
            web.ignoring().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user", "/user/login");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("ESSENTIAL", "PREMIUM")
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setAppUserRepository(AppUserRepository appUserRepository) {
        this.appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<AppUser> optionalAppUser = appUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (optionalAppUser.isEmpty())
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found while trying to load user");

        AppUser appUser = optionalAppUser.get();

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = appUser.getAuthority()
                .stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return User.builder()
                .username(appUser.getUsername())
                .password(appUser.getEncryptedPassword().replace("{bcrypt}", ""))
                .authorities(authorities)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and this is my error response when I call the url with `MockMvc` for `/journals`:

**API call**

```java
@Test
    void checkIfCreatesJournal() throws Exception {
        appUser = new AppUser();
        appUser.setUsername("honggildong");
        appUser.setEmail("a@a.com");
        appUser.setEncryptedPassword("asdfasdfasdf123!");
        Authority authority = new Authority();
        authority.setAuthority(AuthorityType.ESSENTIAL);
        authority.setAppUser(appUser);
        appUser.setAuthority(new HashSet<>(List.of(authority)));

        appUserService.createAppUser(appUser);
        jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(appUser.getUsername());

        String content = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(journalMap);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/journals")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                .content(content)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

        assertThat(journalService.getPaginatedJournals(appUser, 0, 1)
                .getContent().get(0).getStockPrice()).isEqualTo(235.38);
    }
```

**JwtUtil**

```java
@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    private final int expirationTime = 50 * 60 * 60 * 10;
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public JwtUtil(CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
        secret = Keys.secretKeyFor(signatureAlgorithm).getEncoded();
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        return createToken(userDetails);
    }

    private String createToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .claim("authorities", userDetails.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expirationTime))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    ...
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setAppUserRepository(AppUserRepository appUserRepository) {
        this.appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<AppUser> optionalAppUser = appUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (optionalAppUser.isEmpty())
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found while trying to load user");

        AppUser appUser = optionalAppUser.get();

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = appUser.getAuthority()
                .stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority().toString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return User.builder()
                .username(appUser.getUsername())
                .password(appUser.getEncryptedPassword().replace("{bcrypt}", ""))
                .authorities(authorities)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**AuthorityType Enum**

```java
public enum AuthorityType {
    TRIAL,
    ESSENTIAL,
    PREMIUM,
    ADMIN;
}
```

**JwtDecoder**

```java
@Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(
                new SecretKeySpec(jwtSecretProvider.getSecretKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getValue())
        ).build();
    }
```

**JwtSecretProvider**

```java
private String secret;

public JwtSecretProvider() {
    secret = Keys.secretKeyFor(signatureAlgorithm).getEncoded();
}
@Override
    public byte[] getSecretKey() {
        return secret;
    }
```

and the error being:

```
JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@77bce91c, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]

[WWW-Authenticate:"Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
```

Comment: if you will change the authority setter method, somethig like this `authority.setAuthority("ROLE_" + AuthorityType.ESSENTIAL);`  or `authority.setAuthority("SCOPE_" + AuthorityType.ESSENTIAL);` , i think it is going to work.

Comment: What is `jwt` here? You aren't creating it anywhere. You are also creating a user, but where are you adding it to the userservice (or using mocking to return it)? Looks like you think creating some objects randomly will make it work, instead of binding it together.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry I forgot to add them, I've updated the code.

Comment: @AndreiLisa I've changed the authority type to String and changed it to set it to `"SCOPE_" + AuthorityType.ESSENTIAL` but it still produced the same error where the Granted Authorities inside JwtAuthenticationToken being empty

Comment: can you show your AuthorityType Enum as well?

Comment: can you parse your JWT token ?  and see if there are `authorities` that you wait `.hasAnyAuthority("ESSENTIAL", "PREMIUM")` on [jwt](https://jwt.io/) for example

Comment: @AndreiLisa Do you mean the deserialized jwt body? Here's the payload: ```{
  "sub": "honggildong",
  "authorities": [{"authority": "SCOPE_ESSENTIAL"},{"authority": "SCOPE_TRIAL"}],
  "iat": 1693298585,
  "exp": 1693300385
}```

Comment: also please provide your `jwtDecoder()`  method for full understanding of your flow.

Comment: @AndreiLisa Yup added

Comment: on  method  `loadUserByUsername` change the .`map`  function to `                    .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + authority.getAuthority().toString()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @AndreiLisa I did and it's still the same... I also tried to change the `Authority` entity's `authority` to hold `String` type but that also produced the same error.

Comment: ok, i `m going to check this code implementation and after it. I will be able to give a result with an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your implementation to work, you should also declare/configure an authentication converter.

Something like this:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

  private JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

  public JwtAuthConverter() {
    this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
  }

  @Override
  public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream.concat(
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(),
        extractAuthorities(jwt).stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, getPrincipalClaimName(jwt));
  }

  private String getPrincipalClaimName(Jwt jwt) {
    return jwt.getClaim(JwtClaimNames.SUB);
  }

  private Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Jwt jwt) {
    if (jwt.getClaim("authorities") != null) {
      Map<String, Object> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("authorities");
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      List<String> roles = mapper.convertValue(realmAccess.get("authority"),
          new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
          });
      return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_" + role))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

And also construct token with the `authorities` field something like this:

```
"authorities": {
    "authority": [
        "SCOPE_ESSENTIAL"
          ...
      ]
     }
```

After all of this changes in  In `SecurityConfig {...}` class add next one field

```
 private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;
```

Also in `filterChain` you should add this convertor:

replace:

```
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
```

TO

```
oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->

        oauth2.jwt(jwt -> {

            jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder());
            jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter);
        }));
```

Comment: Omg Thank you so much this acutally worked! Thank you so much